# Test Design: How do I simulate the passage of time to test the detection of and response to events scheduled in the future?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, scheduled-tasks, laravel-4

I am working on a web-based lease management application that needs to be able to generate various reports, reminders and alerts every day, based on information in the database at any given time. Some examples of the kind of reports, reminders and alerts include:

- Send a transactional email letting a set of users know that their next invoice is due in 15 days.
- Send a transactional email letting a set of users know that they have 1 or more past-due invoices
- Alert a property manager that a particular property is X days past due and offer to print a set of eviction documents
- etc.

It seems like the simplest approach is to define a collection of scripts that execute via a set of cron jobs every morning. Each script would check for the criteria needed to trigger a specific response from the system. For instance I may have a collection of scripts like, SendInvoiceDueIn15DaysEmail.php, SendInvoicePastDue30DaysEmail.php, etc.

My primary question is, given a database filled with test data, what is the best way to simulate the passage of time, say 90 days, to ensure that the data triggers the correct set of responses each day? Some of my daily tasks need to interact with third party APIs like Mandrill, Mail Chimp, some industry-specific accounting packages, etc.

My secondary question is, if anybody has experience developing applications that center around scheduled, recurring events that happen in the future, am I on the right track here? I've already built most of the core system (user management, property management, lease management), now it's time to test the automated side of things.

For what it's worth the core of application is using Laravel 4, but I don't think is strictly a PHP question.

TL;DR **How do I go about simulating the passage of time in order to check that over a 90 day period the system correctly detects a set of events and triggers an appropriate response which completed successfully?**

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer here is the same as in everything else you wish to test - a Clock mock. Abstract the way you check what time it is right now. Then you could create a mock clock implementation that would work much faster (or report whatever you'd like) during tests and another implementation that would simply return the true time in production.

This way you could also test other scenarios like time changes on the server or Daylight saving time.